# How to reuse multiple activities and layout in linear order for quiz (android)

Tags: android

I have tried looking around but am unsure what category this falls under...

I told a friend Id do a simple quiz app for them however I'm not sure how best to do it.

I have a quiz where you select male or female.
From there, there is either a man or women asking questions to the user, but only every 5 questions. In between there are activities with a different number of options for answers

For example select men, then a male character asks the first question and has two possible answers (one correct, one incorrect)

The next screen (activity) has a question with no man, but 3 possible answers

The next screen has a question with 4 possible answers

the next screen has a question with 2 possible answers

The next screen has a question with 3 possible answers

The next screen has a question with 2 possible answers

The next screen has the man talking to the user asking another question with 2 possible answers again.

This goes on for 30 questions but reuses the same 5 layouts

Also the animations and sounds (activity programming) are the exact same for all questions.

How do i reuse the layout and functional activities while calling different string resources in linear order of questions?

Thanks for your help people of Stack

Answer (score 1):

Use `Fragment`, read more at [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Then in your main `activity`, call `FragmentManager` to switch between `fragments`.

Comment: Thanks mate!
I'lll go watch some tutorials and give it a crack!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Da_Pz could work. You can also try making an `Activity`, lets call it `MainActivity` and you can have an `Activity` for each  of the 5 layouts. The `MainActivity` would call `LayoutActivity1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`, and pass the question as well as the answer options. When the user has picked an answer, the `MainActivity` will launch the next `LayoutActivity` and pass the right question and answer options.

So, you have a `MainActivity` that controls which `LayoutActivity` gets called, and which question/answers need to be displayed.

Let me know if you have any questions, and we can work this out...

Comment: Thanks mate!
I'lll go watch some tutorials and give it a crack!

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use *single layout design* for quiz.Just update only **questions** alternatively with some logics